# assistance with java slot machine

Tags: java, variable-assignment

basically I am designing a slot machine in java using triple string and am having a small problem with it, so far i have:

```
class TripleString {

    public static final int MAX_LEN = 20;

    private String string1;    
    private String string2;    
    private String string3;

    TripleString()    
    {
        string1 ="";    
        string2 ="";    
        string3 ="";    
    }

    public void setTripleString (String str1, String str2, String str3) {    
        string1 = str1;    
        string2 = str2;    
        string3 = str3;    
    }

    public void setStrings(String s1, String s2, String s3){    
        String str1 = s1; String str2 = s2; String str3 = s3;     
    }

    public String getstr1(){    
        return str1();    
    }

    public String getStr2(){    
        return str2();    
    }

    public String getstr3(){    
        return str3();    
    }

    private boolean vaildString( String str ) {    
        if (str.length() >0 && str.length() <= MAX_LEN) {           
            return true;    
        }    
        else {
            return false;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

The problem I am having right now is that when I try to return str1,2,and 3 i am getting an error saying that "the method str1 is undefined for the type tripleString()" Does anyone know how I can fix this?

EDIT: this is another part of the slot machine class called triple string that I am using to define the strings, not the entire program. I have not started the getBet() portion yet

Comment: str1() is not a method, so it is undefined. Try returning "str1" and not "str1()". (And, I haven't reviewed all the code, just saying, your error message is because you're trying to return a method.)

Comment: tried it, it says that it cannot resolve "str1" as a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this method

```
public void setStrings(String s1, String s2, String s3){

    String str1 = s1; String str2 = s2; String str3 = s3;

}
```

You're defining and setting three strings, and then leaving the scope of the `setStrings` method, causing the strings to evaporate.

Actually, what you probably want to do is this:

```
public void setStrings(String s1, String s2, String s3){

    string1 = s1; 
    string2 = s2; 
    string3 = s3;
}
```

Which you're already doing here anyway:

```
public void setTripleString (String str1, String str2, String str3) {  
    string1 = str1;   
    string2 = str2;  
    string3 = str3;  
}
```

And this:

```
public String getstr1(){    
    return str1();    
}

public String getStr2(){    
    return str2();    
}

public String getstr3(){    
    return str3();    
}
```

should probably be this:

```
public String getstring1(){    
    return string1;    
}

public String getString2(){    
    return string2;    
}

public String getstring3(){    
    return string3;    
}
```

Comment: im not completely sure what you mean by defining them as members. how do i do this?

Comment: Already edited my answer.  You've got more problems going on here than a simple mis-assignment.

Comment: unfortunatly when i do that it tells me that the return string method is undefined for triple string, meaning its not using the values from the set strings method as id hoped

Comment: I actually just changed it to that haha than you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as changing "return str1();" to "return str1;". Having the parenthesis at the end is saying you want to return the value returned by calling the method str1().  But str1 is not a method, it would be a String.

However these are undeclared.  You should be returning string1 because that's what you actually have declared. And I would change the casing of your getters to be consistent.

So basically:

```
public String getStr1(){    
    return string1;    
}

public String getStr2(){    
    return string2;    
}

public String getStr3(){    
    return string3;    
}
```